# debug php code of a facebook app present on heroku

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

At first apologies in advance if there is some problem in my ques, i am new to heroku ,my basic problem is i have some messed up code, where i want to test if i am able to fetch facebook variables in my own code and use them..

in my .php file i want to put name for person using my facebook app to displayname array variable of array and url of array should get the application users picture..i took the idea to assign these value via the index.php file provided by facebook itself.

My .php file code is :-

```
$basic = $facebook->api('/me');

$options = array(
'displayName' => he(idx($basic, 'name')),
'image' => array(
'url' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.he($id).'/picture?type=square',
'height => '48',
'width => '48'
)
);
```

but there is something wrong going here which i cant figure out.
i tried to debug it via javascript or other techniques but now able to connect the .php file to some .js file by any means to transfer variable values present in .php file and print them on my browser,i use to edit code at my own system and push it via git and since the code is executed at heroku i cant figure out what errors are creping in..i am using free account as per now so is there any way i can see my code in execution at heroku.. or any help to debug my code efficiently..

Edit1: alternatively is there any way i can pass these variable from my .PHP file to a separate .JS file and print variables in message box or something..any example code  given will help a lot..there are many questions asked in this regard to transfer variables from separate .PHP file to separate .JS file..but i found no direct answer for it, all suggest workarounds but no direct way... questions i visited for it are .. 
[What's the best way to pass a PHP variable to Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766041/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-javascript)

[Grab/input php variable in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494629/grab-input-php-variable-in-javascript)

and some more but dint find the perfect answer.

**Edit2: if my ques needs more info plz let me know,and if second option is the choice left to debug my code ..then can someone give me an example with transferring variable/array present in testfile.php file say present at appfolder/php/lib/testfile.php and output it on browser in HTML format using testjs.js file say present at appfolder/lib/js/testjs.js**

Answer (score 1):

A common exchange format between PHP (or other language) and JavaScript is JSON. You can encode an array (or an php object) to json using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), in PHP. Like this :

```
$options_json = json_encode($options);
```

So, you can write this javascript variable in your html results, like this :

```
echo '<script>var options = ', json_encode($options), ';</script>';
```

Your picture will then be accessible using javascript :

```
console.log(options);
console.log(options.url);
```

Comment: I dont understand this you are using json_encode($options)  in both files ..i.e. in .PHP file as well as in .HTML file ,and what will be the use of variable $options_json then..can u plz elaboate more..and one more ques are these JSON objects global between .PHP file and .HTML/.JAVASCRIPT file